# What am I doing wrong in trying to connect a new head to this mesh?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode

Fairly new to Blender so bear with me here.

I created a mesh in MakeHuman which I then imported to Blender. It came with a full skeleton and a hierarchy looking somewhat like this.

[image: Hierarchy]

I wanted to put my own head on the mesh, so I cut off the old head and placed my new head where the old one was. I wasn't entirely sure what to do with the new head to connect it, but I found a tutorial saying that I could add a constraint "Child-of" modifier to the head and attach it to a bone on the armature. This setting can be seen here.

[image: Constraint Modifier]

All seems well and good while I'm in pose mode, but if I exit pose mode and go to Object or edit mode, I'm faced with this, which I can only assume means I've done something wrong.

[image: Everything is all over the place]

I'm mostly just looking for guidance on how I can ensure all these pieces are properly attached, as I feel I'm missing a simple but important aspect of putting this character together that is going to keep me from progressing. In addition, pose mode is only allowing me to rotate joints (they will not transform in the 3D view) which leads me to believe there may be other problems with this rig. Would appreciate any guidance on how to further diagnose or solve these issues. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: So I've figured out the second half of my question which was "Why are my bones stuck in rotate only mode?". It turns out their locations were all locked in the transform panel. Unfortunately this means when I move a bone it detaches from the skeleton, so I have created another question for myself, but will search for an answer to that as well.

Comment: It looks like in the second image that you went to edit mode on the suit, and by design Blender started ignoring the armature modifier until you leave edit mode again. Are you sure that the suit does not deform in object mode?